# Running into problems while adding kali linux respository in katoonlin popos

Tags: kali-linux, repository, pop-os

I'm running into problems while adding kali linux respository in katoonlin popos:

```
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.XDRMoR1IHT/gpg.1.sh --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys ED444FF07D8D0BF6
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
```

The command I entered is from the katoonlin in the first category which installs the repository I tried other commands that do the same thing and it gave me the same error

I get this error every time I try to add the repository of kali keeping in mind I am using pop-os that is built on ubuntu so what is the problem?

Comment: What's the command you're executing? You seem to have missed that from your question

Comment: I was trying to install the tools of kali lunix and here is the command i was using
kat > 1

1) Add kali linux repositories
2) Update
3) Remove all kali linux repositories
4) View the contents of sources.list file

     
What do you want to do ?> 1
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.j2dzig39sn/gpg.1.sh --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys ED444FF07D8D0BF6

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide extra information. Don't put it in the comments as it isn't easily read by people wanting to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name

You are getting this error due to the script using `--keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net`. SKS has been deprecated and as of June 2021 the site sks-keyservers.net no longer provides DNS records for the pool (hence the "no name" error).

You need to change the script so it will use a non-SKS keyserver such as `keyserver.ubuntu.com`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use repositories from a different distribution

Comment: Katoonlin is like all kali linux tools but the problem is it need repositories of kali and in all ubuntu tutorials it works but when i tried it on popos it dont is there like something diffrent